# 1,2,1,3,2,5,3,7,5,11,8,13,13,17... Print the Nth term

Tags: c

All the odd terms in this series form Fibonacci series and all even terms are prime number in ascending order.

```
#include<stdio.h>    

int main()
{
    int i,n,k,a[100],next,j, P[151],l1,l2,l;   //variables
    scanf("%d", &n);      // input the number on terms
    a[0]=1;
    a[2]=1;
    /* Calculaate Fibonacci series */
    for(i=4;i<n;i+=2)
        a[i]=a[i-2]+a[i-4];
    for(i=0;i<n;i+=2)
        printf(" %d",a[i]);
    for (i = 2; i <=n; ++i)
        P[i] = 0;
    for (i = 2; i <=n; ++i )
    {
        if (P[i] ==0)
           //printf (" %i", i);
           printf(" %d",i);
        for (j = 1; j*i <= n; j++)
            P[i*j] = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot print the terms as shown in the series. How to print terms alternatively.

Comment: `a[0]=1;a[2]=1` is that intentional, that it is `2` and not `1`?

Comment: It is unclear how you build the sequence.  What is the logic behind arranging the numbers like `1,2,1,3,1, ...`

Comment: [std::nth_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) seems to me to be the perfect tool for the job (if I'm understanding the question correctly).

Comment: Do you know how to generate the Fibonacci sequence? Do you know how to generate prime numbers?

Comment: Here the odd places like 1st 3rd 5th and so on r fibbonaci series...1,1,2,3,5,8...

Comment: So shouldn't the sequence be `1,2,1,3,2,5,3,7,5, ...`?

Comment: Yes, sir, i do know to print both the series separately.

Comment: Use two functions: one to compute the prime number and one to compute the Fibonacci number. You might use global variables for the precomputed values to keep it simple.

Comment: Yes sir , I think 1 is mistakenly printed in question. I appolozise for the mistake.

Comment: I have seen the same question asked a few days ago. Is this an assignment for some class you share with the other author?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do something similar to:

```
void intersperse_print(const int* arr1, const int* arr2, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
        printf(" %d %d", arr1[i], arr2[i]);
    }
}
```

So once you populate `a` (with Fibonacci numbers) and `P` (with prime numbers),
call it:

```
intersperse_print(a, P, 100);
```

Comment: I think the objective is to print only the Nth term.

Comment: @Sandeep: From title, yes, but the whole question tends to be to *"print terms alternatively."*.

Comment: We can replace size with the number of terms we want, I think it will be solved